# How to create custom table after installing my own module?

Tags: sugarcrm

I have build a custom module that work with its own custom tables. Module works fine on my local server and now I want to move my custom module to production/live  server.
But I'm unable to find hook after_install module,that can install my tables.

> Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add  `pre_execute` and `post_execute` action hooks into your package's manifest file.
https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/03/02/howto-add-custom-actions-during-a-module-installation/
You may run into limitations of the On-Demand service depending on what you are trying to do.